# grails swedish characters in domains-inlist will be garbage in the GSP-SELECT

Tags: grails, gsp

Following code will garbage the character "ä" in "Preliminär" when printed by the GSP.

If I use an automatic generated view it doesn't garbage.
What can I do to fix this?
Is there a way to inspect the code generated by the generated code:

```
        <fieldset class="form">
            <f:all bean="request1"/>
        </fieldset>
```

My code:

```
Domain    
class Request1 {
  String    status
  static constraints = {
  status(inList: ["Preliminär", "Aktiv", "Avslutad", "Cancellerad"])
}

GSP
            <g:form action="save">
            <fieldset class="form">Ange status: <g:select name="status" from="${request1.constrainedProperties.status.inList}" 
          value="${request1?.status}"/>
           </fieldset>
```

Comment: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Encoding-settings-to-deal-with-Swedish-characters-td1575454.html

Comment: I've already read that but they never come to a solution. The strange thing here is that the letters displays correct if I use a view that is created by the command generate-all. So in some way settings looks alright.

Comment: possibly a bug then with i presume scaffolding ? I think you need to provide steps of what works and what doesn't maybe needs to be raised as an issue

Comment: I tried to create a new simple application that only had a single domain with just this status-column. I thought I should attach it to my question for demonstration. Problem is that this time it worked and when I checked the original application it worked there too. So I have to wait until it happends next time ;-)